# Uniform convergence of characteristic functions by integrating by parts

Tags: integration, probability-theory, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of real random variable converging in distribution to $X.$

Prove that $\varphi_{X_n}$ converges uniformly to $\varphi_X$ on every compact $K \subset \mathbb{R},$ by considering ***an integration by parts for $\int e^{ixy}dP_{X_n}(x).$***

Can't see how to integrate by parts. Any hints?

Comment: $ \int_{-M}^{M}e^{iux}dF_n(x)-\int_{-M}^{M}e^{iux}dF_(x)
=e^{iux}[F_n(x)-F(x)]_{-M}^M
-iu \int_{-M}^{M}[F_n(x)-F(x)]e^{iux}dx $

Comment: $F_n$ is the distribution function of $X_n$?

Comment: Yes, $F_n$ is the distribution function of $X_n$.